# Python cannot use threading, gets attribute error

Tags: python

I'm trying to declare an object of a class that is defined in a local .py-file
that I have not written myself. The declaration goes like this:

```
GPS_thread = GPS()
GPS_thread.run()
```

When it reaches the second line the program crashes and gives the error "AttributeError:_Thread__target". I have no idea what this means.

I have tried to look up other forum threads on similar subjects and found that they often recomend that I try to look for a local file called "threading" which is blocking the view of the proper file. The only thing I could fins was threading.pyc, the compiled version of threading.py, which is imported in the GPS-library. I deleted it, but that did not help.

Any advice?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python\mscript\controlc.py", line 228, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Python\mscript\controlc.py", line 140, in main
    GPS_thread.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 767, in run
    del self.__target, self.__args, self.__kwargs
AttributeError: _Thread__target
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback (all of the error message).

Comment: GPS - Global Positioning System. I'm working with a project that uses GPS-devices. The code controling them is in a particular, locally written library.

Answer (score 4):

run is what you override, but don't call: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run).
Use `GPS_thread.start()`, this will fork and call `GPS_thread.run` in the background. [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start)

Comment: The __init__(self) of the GPS-class calls the start()-method, which I guess then calls the (locally defined) run()-method. Manually calling the run()-method apparently was a misguided attempt to solve another problem.